# iphone: how to display sqlite data from diff. statement of query in diff. view?

Tags: iphone, sql, ios, sqlite

I was able to get a list of title of the books (tableview) and when i select the book i would like to push to the new view of the details of the books. Do i do it in titleView class 'didSelectRow' or in DetailView class 'viewWillAppear' and if so what exactly do I have to put to get the statement, 3 or contentInfo?

Database Class

```
 (NSArray *) itemsByAuthorID:(NSInteger)authorID {
        NSMutableArray *retval = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSString *query;
        code....
        query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from books where books.author_id  = '%i'", authorID];
        }
        code...
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK){
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                int itemID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
                int authorID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1);
                char *nameChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
                char *itemContent = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
                NSString *contentTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:nameChars];
                NSString *contentInfo = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:itemContent];
                Item *info = [[Item alloc] initWithItemID:itemID authorID:authorID contentTitle:(NSString *)contentTitle contentInfo:contentInfo];
                [retval addObject:info];
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        return retval;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a private class for Book and retrive data from database for all books in array of Book.

Then after when didSelectRow is called only pass object of Book as parameter and show details in Detail view.

Comment: this is my private class called Item look at code below. What can I put for the didSelectRow to pass that object of contentInfo?

..........Item *info = [[Item alloc] initWithItemID:itemID authorID:authorID contentTitle:(NSString *)contentTitle contentInfo:contentInfo];
                [retval addObject:info];